# How to show total view count across all posts for an author

Tags: posts, author, views

I'm using [wp-postviews](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wp-postviews/) to track views for posts by authors on my site. It stores the view count in  the post meta field `$views`. I'd want to show on their profile a total count of views for all their posts combined. How to do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A list of posts in the format:

> #### Post views by Author: Author Name
>
> - Post Title (15)
> - Post Title (67)
> - Post Title (4)
>
> ---
>
> Total Number of views: **86**

```
$author_id = ''; // do stuff to get user ID

$author_posts = get_posts( array(
    'author' => $author_id
) );

$counter = 0; // needed to collect the total sum of views

echo '<h3>Post views by Author:</h3><ul>'; // do stuff to get author name
foreach ( $author_posts as $post )
{
    $views = absint( get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'views', true ) );
    $counter += $views;
    echo "<li>{$post->post_title} ({$views})</li>";
}
echo "</ul><hr /><p>Total Number of views: <strong>{$counter}</strong></p>";
```

Comment: Pretty cool! I didn't want to list all the post titles so I just took that line out but the loop is needed to add up all the views right? Is this going to be expensive if the user has 1,000 posts?

Comment: simply test it with `timer_start()` and `timer_stop()` as it depends on your setup.